# How to rename a list-associated SPD2013 WF?

Tags: 2013, powershell, designer-workflow

I have 20 sites that all have the same SPD2013 WF - it is a WF that executes on a specific list when an item is added or changed. We goofed on the naming of the WF and would like to rename the WF. Is there a feasible way to do this via PowerShell without breaking the WF? I recognize that the list column for the WF would also have to be changed. Any help appreciated.